# How to translate an input using a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

So the goal of this task is translate english input values into french and vice versa. The problem here is that I don't know how to split the whole input by spaces to get all the words one by one and translate them one by one. Thank you :)

```
function translateInput(){
    for(i = 0; i < ('input').length; i++){
        ('input').eq(i).val(('value').eq(i).text());
   }
}

var translateText = function() {
    var translationType = document.getElementById('translation').value;

    if (translationType === 'englishToFrench') {
        console.log('translation used: English to French');
        return 'code1';
    }else if(translationType === 'frenchToEnglish'){
        console.log('translation used: French to English');
        return 'code2';
    }else{
        return "No valid translation selected.";
    }
};
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function to split the string at its spaces into an array.

```
var str = YOUR_STRING;
var array = str.split(" ");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Then you can loop through the array and translate word by word.

```
    var arrayLength = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        alert(array[i]);
        //Translate string
    }
```

Comment: How would you do this using a function?

Comment: Because a friend suggested I make two functions, one to split up the words and another to translate them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a [Regular Expression](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp), by the way you can practice in a [Regex Playground](http://regexr.com/).

```
var myString = "Hello, my name is JavaScript";
var tokens = a.match(/\w+'?\w*/g); //Assuming you can take words like {"Bonsanto's", "Asus'"}

tokens.forEach(function(word){
    console.log(word);
});
```